# stanford.edu free SQL course question one

Tags: sql, sqlite

Students at your hometown high school have decided to organize their social network using databases. So far, they have collected information about sixteen students in four grades, 9-12. Here's the schema:

Highschooler ( ID, name, grade ) 
English: There is a high school student with unique ID and a given first name in a certain grade.

Friend ( ID1, ID2 ) 
English: The student with ID1 is friends with the student with ID2. Friendship is mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Friend table, so is (456, 123).

Likes ( ID1, ID2 ) 
English: The student with ID1 likes the student with ID2. Liking someone is not necessarily mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Likes table, there is no guarantee that (456, 123) is also present.

Question:

> Find the names of all students who are friends with someone named
>   Gabriel.

I went through the videos provided in this course and I'm pretty discouraged because I feel like I have no idea how to answer this question. I think i need to re-watch the series of video and maybe find a tutor (Any tutors out there :) ) I tried writing the below SQL.

```
select distinct h.name
from highschooler h, Friend f
where and f.id1 > f.id2 
and h.id = (
  select h.id 
  from highschooler 
  where name = 'Gabriel'
);
```

The answer should be...

Jordan
Cassandra
Andrew
Alexis
Jessica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join twice `Highschooler` to `Friend`:

```
select h2.name 
from Friend f
inner join highschooler h1 on f.id1 = h1.id 
inner join highschooler h2 on f.id2 = h2.id
where h1.name = 'Gabriel';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ez9LXcmC3erVz7cFb9ravE/0).

```
CREATE TABLE Highschooler (id INTEGER, name TEXT, grade INTEGER);
INSERT INTO Highschooler (id, name, grade) VALUES 
 (1,'Bob',9),
 (2,'Alice',10),
 (3,'Gabriel',11),
 (4,'John',12),
 (5,'Nick',12),
 (6,'Mary',11),
 (7,'Lisa',10),
 (8,'Sandra',9),
 (9,'Tom',10),
 (10,'Jack',11);

CREATE TABLE Friend (id1 INTEGER, id2 INTEGER);
INSERT INTO Friend (id1 , id2) VALUES 
 (2,5), (5,2),
 (1,3), (3,1),
 (6,7), (7,6),
 (10,3), (3,10),
 (7,10), (10,7),
 (4,6), (6,4);
Results:
| name |
| ---- |
| Bob  |
| Jack |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew this was a simple one but for I'm having a hard time implementing what I learn in the videos. This helps!